# Slow internet connection in Ubuntu 22.04 Beta

Tags: networking, 22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 Beta version - the network is very slow and it almost can't refresh repos with `sudo apt update`. I have choose the nearest server, but it still doesn't work. Will we have a fix on this? I know that this is Beta software but I don't want to downgrade or reinstall the OS yet.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: If you wish to report bugs, firstly thank you for helping test the release, but please see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and use a #ubuntu+1 site such as IRC, https://ubuntuforums.org/ etc. *This site isn't tracked for ubuntu+1 or #ubuntu-next issues*

Comment: Wired or Wireless?

Comment: I hope you can point out is this a server issue or not by trying the same network with Ubuntu 21.10, 20.04, or even Windows 11 and try to reproduce the problem, as 22.04 isn't on-topic yet.

Comment: @waltinator I use wireless network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a problem related to the server not the distro, try again changing other servers around your area, if it doesn't work it may be the distro then if not your internet provider. But I think is because of the server, sometimes the nearest server doesn't mean the fastest, I had the same problem in the past, and I solve it by selecting a server from the US, which is the closest country I have in my current location. I hope it works.

Comment: I agree with you about this. I changed the server to the US and it works, but the network stills be slow (now it effects to the browser) and some times, apt download files just about 160B - 2kB. I will check for my problem and fix it. Thank you so much!